# Conditional statement for "two or more of five variables match a condition"?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have five variables as columns in a data frame and want to select those rows in which two or more variables contain values larger than 5:

```
A B C D E
1 2 1 8 7 <- two variables larger than 5
2 7 2 4 3
8 3 2 4 9 <- ditto
```

**How can I select those rows using a conditional statement?**

I can do it by explicitly listing all combinations, but there must be an easier way:

```
(A > 5 & B > 5) | (A > 5 & C > 5) | ...
```

Comment: For a data.frame, dat, you could do `dat[rowSums(dat > 5) > 1,]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

`( A>5 + B>5 + C>5 + D>5 + E>5 ) >= 2`

Since logical values are coerced to binary with `TRUE` coercing to 1 and `FALSE` to 0, you can add the logical values and see if you have two or more.